# Index page of gii doesn't work fine: lack of css style

Tags: php, yii

Something wrong with index:

[image: Something wrong with index.]

It doesn't work out. The success one is like this:

[image: the correct one]

The config of nginx is right. So, why can't I see the page with correct css style?

Comment: location /{
            root   E:/php_test/basic/web;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  
            $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

Comment: the code structure is installed by composer. I didn't make any change.

Comment: try checking the console if it is throwing `404` for the css files check the path it is using

Comment: no 404 error throwed, but output this in console---"index.php?r=gii:11 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/assets/e5014848/css/bootstrap.css"."

Comment: and then I tried to change reponse content-type,but didn't find where to modify.....

Comment: just asking you are trying to access it on local machine?

Comment: At last,I used a strange way to resolve.I changed the code of this view page"<!DOCTYPE html>" to "<!DOCTYPE plain>".It worked!  But it means that I must have changed every layout in every view.....It's not a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: and what is the version of yii2 ?

Comment: oh, I get . click the link and I can see the css file,no problem

Comment: the version is 2.0.14.1

Comment: you mean `2.0.14.1`.

Comment: yes，I use Yii::getVersion()，get the version information

Comment: you have to check for the mime types for your server

Answer (score 0):

I finally get the answer.The reason is something wrong with my nginx.
nginx before:

```
location / {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

nginx now:

```
location / {
    # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

That's the reason!  I didn't handle those static resources forwarding right.So, the js/css files are transmitted to fastcgi ,and then they are all changed to txt.

Thanks for all volunteers under this question!Both of you really do great help to me~~